# How do you download and extract a gzipped file with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, gzip

I need to periodically download, extract and save the contents of http://data.dot.state.mn.us/dds/det_sample.xml.gz to disk. Anyone have experience downloading gzipped files with C#?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To compress:

```
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test.docx.gzip", 
FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fStream, 
    CompressionMode.Compress)) {
        byte[] inputfile = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test.docx");
        zipStream.Write(inputfile, 0, inputfile.Length);
    }
}
```

To Decompress:

```
using (FileStream fInStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test.docx.gz", 
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fInStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {   
        using (FileStream fOutStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test1.docx", 
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
            byte[] tempBytes = new byte[4096];
            int i;
            while ((i = zipStream.Read(tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length)) != 0) {
                fOutStream.Write(tempBytes, 0, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from a post I wrote last year that shows how to decompress a gzip file using C# and the built-in GZipStream class.
http://blogs.msdn.com/miah/archive/2007/09/05/zipping-files.aspx

As for downloading it, you can use the standard [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) classes in .NET.

Comment: +1 The link was helpful to me just now using compression for the first time.  Nice, useful, concise blog entry.

Answer (score 7):

You can use WebClient in System.Net to download:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://data.dot.state.mn.us/dds/det_sample.xml.gz", " C:\mygzipfile.gz");
```

then use [#ziplib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx) to extract

Edit: or GZipStream... forgot about that one

Answer (score 5):

Try the [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/), a C# based library for compressing and uncompressing files using gzip/zip.

Sample usage can be found on this [blog post](http://dotnet.org.za/thea/archive/2006/01/17/Unzip-files-programmatically-in-C_2300_-_2D00_-_2300_ZipLib.aspx):

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

FastZip fz = new FastZip();       
fz.ExtractZip(zipFile, targetDirectory,"");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class in the System.Net namespace to request the file and download it.  Then use [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class in the System.IO.Compression namespace to extract the contents to the location you specify.  They provide examples.

Answer (score 2):

The [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HttpContext` object to download a csv.gz file

Convert you `DataTable` into string using `StringBuilder` (`inputString`)

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv.gz", fileName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

You can extract this downloaded file using 7Zip