# Download URL Content-Disposition excel file using C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, content-disposition

I need to download a file attached to a URL using C# and I have written this piece of code:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            string disposition = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];

            string filename = disposition.Substring(disposition.IndexOf("filename=") + 9).Replace("\"", "");

            using (var fs = new FileStream(filename.Replace("/", "-"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fs);
            }
```

But the excel file saved in the path seems to be corrupted

Comment: the path http://members.xyz.com/xyz/excel/xyz.aspx?d=0 leads to nowhere, any i suggest using [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.5.2#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFile_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: I Updated the URL. Please have a look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a forbidden back when trying to call your URL. In my example I have used a different URL which is working fine.

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://spreadsheetpage.com/downloads/xl/king-james-bible.xlsm");
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        using (var fs = new FileStream("king-james-bible.xlsm", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
        }
```

Could it be that the file your retrieving itself is corrupt?

**Updated based on the new information**

Okay the link is now working for me. Your problem is that the Excel file is sent using a gzip encoding. The code sample below works with your URL.

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");//"http://spreadsheetpage.com/downloads/xl/king-james-bible.xlsm");
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        string disposition = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];

        string filename = disposition.Substring(disposition.IndexOf("filename=") + 9).Replace("\"", "");

        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename.Replace("/", "-"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    byte[] tempBytes = new byte[4096];
                    int i;
                    while ((i = zipStream.Read(tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(tempBytes, 0, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have used the info from this post for the gzip decoding: [How do you download and extract a gzipped file with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833/how-do-you-download-and-extract-a-gzipped-file-with-c)

Comment: Actually the URL I use is not directly pointing to the excel file. It has an attachment which I get its name from Content-Disposition header info

Comment: @aminmohammadi I have updated the answer based on your input

Comment: @PaulHieltjes Do we have to make call `response.Close()` at the end?